# Не могу составить алгоритм спавна ресурсов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется скрипт, который должен:
При столкновении с обьектом который имеет имя derevo - удалять данный обьект и создавать его клон в рандомном месте, после чего, если столкнуться склоном -создать еще один такой же клон и так до бесконечности. Что собственно я сделал:

```
 public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) 
 { 
     if(coll.gameObject.tag == "derevo") 
     { 
         Destroy(coll.gameObject); 
         var derevo = GameObject.Find("derevo"); 
         GameObject clone = Instantiate(derevo, new Vector3(Random.Range(-20 , 18), 0, 0), Quaternion.identity); 
         clone.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true; 
     } 
 }
```

Итог: 
Один раз срабатывает, после чего обьект derevo удаляется соответсвенно и на следующий раз уже код не может найти данный обьект чтобы его копировать.
Я пытался копировать не по названию, а по тегу, но ничего не получилось.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала давайте опишу последовательность действий, которую вы совершаете:
- Уничтожаете объект, с которым произошло столкновение
- Ищите где-нибудь на сцене объект с именем "derevo"(если его нет - вернётся null, а ведь вы его только что уничтожили)
- Создаёте копию найденного объекта (если он не был найден, то произойдёт ошибка, т.к. нельзя создать клон пустоты)

Другими словами вы зачем-то ищете объект, на который у вас уже есть ссылка, но перед этим вы его вообще уничтожаете. Вот такой код будет работать нормально:

```
 public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) 
 { 
     if(coll.gameObject.tag == "derevo") 
     { 
         GameObject clone = Instantiate(coll.gameObject, new Vector3(Random.Range(-20 , 18), 0, 0), Quaternion.identity); 
         clone.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true; 
         Destroy(coll.gameObject); 
     } 
 }
```

Ну и вообще - операции удаления и создания объектов одни из самых ресурсоёмких в Unity. Зачем вам создавать клон дерева, если можно переместить само дерево, с которым вы столкнулись? :)

```
 public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) 
 { 
     if(coll.gameObject.tag == "derevo") 
     { 
         var newPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-20 , 18), 0, 0);
         coll.gameObject.transform.position = newPos; 
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сохранить дерево как префаб, и создавать его, а не объект со сцены. В [этой](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Prefabs.html) странице официальной документации описан сам префаб, а вот в [этой](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html) - как создавать их на сцене. Также есть много видео на ютубе, ищите по слову префаб или prefab. Использование префабов - один из основных механизмов юнити, и очень удобный. Осваивайте!